# R: count of the number of entries in a column excluding the blanks

Tags: r, dataframe, bioinformatics

My data looks like this:

```
CHROM           Mutant_SNP_2
3RD                 T
4RD                 C
5RD                 
6RD                 G
7RD                 A
8RD
```

I have a CSV dataframe. I want a count from column "Mutant_SNP_2" of how many rows have an entry and therefore don't want a count of any blanks " ". I am separating it out by column "CHROM". I am getting the right output in terms of layout using this code in `dplyr`: 
`count(combined, Mutant_SNP_2, wt = CHROM, sort = FALSE)` however it is only counting the blank rows rather than those with a value. Any idea much appreciated.
The output I get:

```
 Mutant_SNP_2                         CHROM.x     n
         (fctr)                          (fctr) (int)
1               gi|339957448|gb|AENI01001139.1|    23
2               gi|339957449|gb|AENI01001138.1|     9
3               gi|339957451|gb|AENI01001136.1|    97
4               gi|339957452|gb|AENI01001135.1|   116
5               gi|339957453|gb|AENI01001134.1|   175
6               gi|339957454|gb|AENI01001133.1|     2
7               gi|339957455|gb|AENI01001132.1|    78
8               gi|339957456|gb|AENI01001131.1|    51
9               gi|339957457|gb|AENI01001130.1|     2
10              gi|339957458|gb|AENI01001129.1|    52
..          ...                             ...   ...
```

Comment: Can you share full code and a reproducible output? For your example `nrow(df[df$Mutant_SNP_2!="",])` would work though.

Comment: Thanks, that does give me the number of rows without blanks- thanks! But I need it to be by each new category of the CHROM column e.g by ="CHROM" or something?

Comment: @mtoto....above comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with function `table`, the line with `TRUE` will give you the number of not blank value, by `CHROM` value)  :

```
table(df$Mutant_SNP_2!="", df$CHROM)
```

You can get the result directly with `table(df$Mutant_SNP_2!="", df$CHROM)[2, ]`

*Example:*

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(CHROM=sample(letters[1:3], 10, replace=TRUE), Mutant_SNP_2=sample(c("", "not blank"), 10, replace=TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

table(df$Mutant_SNP_2!="", df$CHROM)
#        a b c
#  FALSE 0 2 3
#  TRUE  2 2 1

table(df$Mutant_SNP_2!="", df$CHROM)[2, ]
# a b c 
# 2 2 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked. I am not sure why the other suggestions didn't work, they all seemed to say don't count the blanks, but they still did, no idea why! Do you mind please telling me what the final [2, ] does? You're a star!

Comment: @Cathyt10 you're welcome, glad that I could help you. `[2, ]` select the second row of the object returned by the call to `table`

Comment: @Cathyt10 oh and I'm in no way a star, just a tiny little fairy ;-)

Answer (score 1):

We could try summing the boolean vector `df$Mutant_SNP_2 != ""` grouped by `CHROM`. This works because `TRUE`'s will be coerced to `1`, while `FALSE`'s to `0`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(CHROM) %>%
  summarise(n = sum(Mutant_SNP_2 != "")) 

   CHROM     n
  (fctr) (int)
1    3RD     1
2    4RD     1
3    5RD     0
4    6RD     1
5    7RD     1
6    8RD     0
```

Comment: Thanks again. Strangely that is now counting all of the entries except those which have an entry e.g the blanks:                               CHROM.x     n
                            (fctr) (int)
1  gi|339957448|gb|AENI01001139.1|   593
2  gi|339957449|gb|AENI01001138.1|    31
3  gi|339957450|gb|AENI01001137.1|    25
4  gi|339957451|gb|AENI01001136.1|  1293
5  gi|339957452|gb|AENI01001135.1|  1056
6  gi|339957453|gb|AENI01001134.1|  1356
7  gi|339957454|gb|AENI01001133.1|    22
8  gi|339957455|gb|AENI01001132.1|   750

Comment: please edit your question with expected output **based on your example data**

Comment: I expect it to look exactly as it is coming out as shown above, but it is counting the blanks and not the entries. Obviously a problem to do with the format of my data. I will try entering as txt or something. Thanks.

Comment: Please update your post or delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[ Mutant_SNP_2 != "", .(count = .N), by=CHROM]
```

Perhaps this?

```
setDT(df)[ ,.(count= length(unique(Mutant_SNP_2))),  by=CHROM]
```

Comment: Thanks that kind of works, but as with the code from mtoto, it actually counts the blanks rather then the entries. Strange, obviously a problem with my data format.

Answer (score 0):

We can `ave` from  `base R` to do this

```
with(df1, as.numeric(ave(Mutant_SNP_2, CHROM, 
               FUN= function(x)  sum(nzchar(x)))))
#[1] 1 1 0 1 1 0
```